# Error while Deserializing JSON responce of WCF Data service

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, winrt-xaml

I am developing an app which user WCF data service. The JSON response contains "&id" and "$ref" keywords. I want to deserialize that JSON with NewtonSoft lib. So I tried to develop classes for JSON so I used www.json2csharp.com but it doesn't give me proper class structures. So I update classes with this

```
[DataMember(Name = "$id", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
public string Id { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "$ref", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
public string Ref { get; set; }
```

Then also not working. While searching I found [a way](http://www.jaressloo.com/2012/05/using-jsons-special-properties-of-ref-and-id/), but it uses JavaScript. So please help to solve my this problem. Web service uses entity framework and it's WCF Service Library project. The sample JSON response is like [this](http://pastebin.com/PMAWs3vk).

Comment: did you try removing the $ from the names in json?

Comment: yes tried but not getting all values as objects

Comment: yes I am getting some values but I think they are not proper, how to get those `ref` objects ? actually each method of service returns different JSONs, so do I have to create different different classes ?

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: I am not getting all the values, some values are null.